# Troubleshooting Keyvaults. Why is AzureDiagnostics not showing any logs?

Tags: azure-keyvault

The metrics for a keyvault are indicating failures.
In an effort to pinpoint the issue, I have enabled Log Analytics in Diagnostics for the keyvault.
It's been hours.

Yet, Log Analytics is showing no data in AzureDiagnostics

of course it's not showing any data for the more specific query:

```
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider =="MICROSOFT.KEYVAULT"
```

Any idea what is required to get queries on AzureDiagnostics to work?
Any other helpful ideas in troubleshooting keyvault failures, would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the reason that you do not accept the answer?! Also no response. If you still want to solve the problem, please give more questions. Or if it solves your problem, please accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, the data wasn't showing because of a 500 custom field limit per workspace was reached. Once support increased it, KV log analytics became visible again

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how do you do to enable the Diagnostics for the Key Vault. I'll show the steps below which I have done and it works well:

**Key Vault -> Diagnostics settings -> Add diagnostics settings**

[image]

Here is the screenshot that makes the query, the event has done before the query only several munites:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for verifying Charles.
I did exactly the same. And yet nothing shows up when querying logs.
I'll raise an SR. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: @user13320475 If the events have done for a long time?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why the AzureDiagnostics are not logging
1 You have not enabled the diagnostics logs properly
2 You have chosen resource specific option when configuring diagnostic logs which will dump the logs only to the specific resource tables and not to AzureDiagnostics.